Tagging releases in a monorepo, in trunk
We have a monorepo and are using trunk based development (single trunk branch)
We have 2 environments dev and prods, and we want to tag the latest releases.
Should we tag each release env commit?
Like "latest-dev" and "latest-prod"?
Or should we stick to only "latest"?
I wish to understand the best practices around managing this situation.
Do keep in mind we need to be able to do diffing before releasing, so any repo that didnt change must not be released, hence why we need the tags. Also, the release pipeline releases to prod and dev, but only releases to prod once dev is done and approved,so if there are issues in dev, we would cancel the pipeline but the latest dev would be different than latest prod
